# How to access app classes from another workspace target in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

In my app, I added an app extension as a target. However I cannot access main app classes from the extension module.

How to access main classes from this target module?

Answer (score 1):

You either have to create an embedded framework and add those classes there so they are available to all targets that embed the framework, or (which is not recommended or considered a good pattern) to include the class in both targets.

Apple has a handy guide on [embedded frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) and how to share code between targets.