# What is the UIButton Navigation push equivalent in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a workspace that I need the main view that use buttons to push to the other projects that contain their respective views. This was simple to achieve in UI Storyboard however it does not seem to be here without implementing a navigationView.

```
Button(action: {
    print("Button action")
}) {
    Image("LIVEMENU")
}
.padding(.vertical, 2.5)
.padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
```

Is the current implemention as it was a placeholder til now.

This is what I was used to

```
- (IBAction)GoToNext:(id)sender 
{
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *without a navigation controller*?

Comment: NavigationView @pawello2222 (edited to reflect that)

Comment: But then you will not have navigation bar back arrows, title etc. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes I understand that which is why I want the navigation handled this way. (custom navigation)

Comment: To be clear the views it will link to have navigation views in them. I plan to have a home button embedded on the top of those views to get back to the main view. @pawello2222

Comment: Consider approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446820/12299030, by changing type of transition you can modify the direction of second view appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `NavigationView` but you may hide it.

Try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isLinkActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Go to...") {
                    // activate link programmatically
                    self.isLinkActive = true
                }
            }
            // hide navigation bar
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .hidden()
            )
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Go back") {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: the second view is in the workspace and not the same swift file @pawello2222 or am I understanding the code here wrong?

Comment: @RealTechyGod It doesn't have to be in the same file.

Comment: [main.Swift](https://pastebin.com/J4Yg1wJh) this might help as I'm running into difficultly implementing that. I will continue troubleshooting

Comment: if I'm following correctly @pawello2222 I would need to somehow call the other project into the SecondView correct? or is there a simpler way to essentially throw control of the app to the other project?

Comment: @RealTechyGod This might help you: [How to access app classes from another workspace target in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463440/how-to-access-app-classes-from-another-workspace-target-in-xcode)

Comment: so what should be a framework is showing up as an app... great another question

Comment: To finish this question is it not possible to get the new view to render full screen rather in just the scrollview? @pawello (thanks for your help over the past few days/questions

Comment: @RealTechyGod Please test the code in the answer in the playground - it *is* full screen.

Comment: @RealTechyGod Btw did you upvote a bunch of my questions recently?

Comment: Yes lol (at least ones I understood a little of)... had nothing better todo. @pawello222 Didn't think you'd notice since your already in the Top0.5% lol

Comment: I actually tested it in the app and it only takes over the scrollview presenting a problem... I might have implemented it in the wrong place though

Comment: @RealTechyGod I did notice your upvotes :) But in reality this will not help much - see [Voting reversal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319068/voting-reversal).

Comment: interesting I defiantly didn't have time to do 80 though... most likely around 10-15 @pawello2222

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219845/discussion-between-realtechygod-and-pawello2222).